# C: replace string in a file WITHOUT temp file or loading into memory

Tags: c, file

I'm studying for an exam which most likely will have a question like this:

Write a C program that processes a file replacing a string A with a string B, WITHOUT using a temp file or loading the file in memory.

It's not actually always like that, but sort of. The strings A and B can be of any length (A < B, A > B, or B may depend on something else).

I'm going mad trying to do this! I'm not asking for code, but for some guidance on what combination of fseek, fgetc, fputc, etc. to use or anything. This problem is quite strange, the most common thing is either to load the whole file in memory, or use a temp file, and I haven't found anything like this anywhere else

EDIT: 
I'm allowed to use posix's `ftruncate`

Comment: 1. List the occurrences first, eg. using fgetc, 2. resize the buffer by reallocating and with setvbuf i guess, 3. replace from the end beginning for A>B or from the start for A<B. Am i missing something?

Comment: How do you already know the questions for the exam?

Comment: So if B is shorter than A, how do you propose to truncate the file to the new (shorter) length? AFAIK, the C standard only allows a file to be truncated to zero length; there is no standardized method to shorten a file to an arbitrary length.  In other words, if you want to shorten a file, you either need a copy of the file in memory, or in a temporary file. Or you need to use a non-standard function like `truncate`.

Comment: Well I'm thinking of grep. I don't know the exact way that uses the memory, but I don't think it loads the entire file, so, it could be implemented on a similar way.

Comment: @ott-- there are tons of exams taken in previous years and they're all very similar

Comment: Draw a line through the question.  Write 'STUPID REQUIREMENT/QUESTION. ANY SANE DEVELOPER WOULD USE A TEMP FILE' around the line. Answer one of the other questions in that section instead.

Comment: Oh - and if the only other question avaliable is about swapping two ints without usiing a temp var, rip up the paper, walk out and find another course.

Comment: "Without ...  loading the file in memory"?  It's impossible to examine the contents of the file without loading it into memory.  This is literally like saying "Read this book, but you can't look at the pages."

Comment: You dont load the file into the memory but you load only one char each time.
Every normal developer dont use fread/fget for this problem but use mmap.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

1. Go and read char by char. until you find a[0] save this address.
2. now read char by char (fgetc) and check if fileChar=a[i] for every i.
3. if not seek to address+1 and go to 1.
4. if yes you seek to address and write.

If  B>A you can seek to the end of the file end write every char to the next place until you have enough space to put B. Similar solution is if A>B. but inverse.

Their is nicer solution for finding the place of A. 
You can use rolling Hash for this. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash

Comment: @ott--  You can't solve this problem without read the chars.. if you use fgetc this is in the memory.And this solution not load the file into the memory..

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-pseudo code.  The really tricky part is when a partial pattern was found but the rest does not match, how to re-sync the partial pattern with the current match-state.  Code prints the lead character of the pattern and then see how the remaining partial pattern matches the pattern.

```
int replace(FILE *inf, FILE *outf, const char *i_pattern, const char *o_pattern) {
  const unsigned char *ip = i_pattern;
  int ch;
  assert(i_pattern && *i_pattern && o_pattern);
  while ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == *ip) {
      advance ip
      if (ip at \0)  {
        write the o_pattern, ip = i_pattern 
      }
      continue;
    }
    i_len = number of matching ch in i_pattern;
    if (i_len == 0) {
      output ch;
      continue;
    }
    // Now the tricky bit
    print i_pattern[0];

    for (i=1; i_len > 0; i++) {
      if (match(&i_pattern[0], &i_pattern[i], i_len)) {
        ip--
        continue `while (ch...)` loop
      }
      print i_pattern[i];
      ip--, i_len--;
    }
  }
  print (i_pattern, length:(ip - i_pattern );
  return non-zero if IO error occurred.
}
```

Notice that the `for (i=1; i_len > 0; i++) {` loop is not dependent on `ch`.  So the amount to shift the partial matched pattern can be pre-computed at start-up rather than recalculated each time.  With this extra work and memory, the algorithm may be `O(File_length + pattern_length)`.